# Completely hide bullet when using itemize

Tags: spacing, indentation, itemize

When using the following command

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[] foo
\item[] bar
\end{itemize}
```

I guess the margins around the bullets are still visible, and thus my items seem to be indented. How can I manage for my items not to be indented AT ALL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to create list to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{noitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[noitemize]{label={}, labelsep=0pt, leftmargin=0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some reference text.

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item[] bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={}]
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={}, labelsep=0pt, leftmargin=0pt]
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{noitemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{noitemize}

\end{document}
```

In successive steps above, I remove the bullet, then the indentation and also set the left margin. Alternatively, and perhaps better, create  list that suits your needs entirely (`noitemize`).